# c# instantiating custom objects

Tags: c#

Hey so far I have and I'm getting a null pointer error in my for loop
anybody know why?
thanks

here is the error message

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
    board = new BoardSquare[15][];

    String boardHtml = "";

     for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < 15; k++) {
                //if (board[i][k] == null)
                    board[i][k] = new BoardSquare(i, k);
                boardHtml += board[i][k].getHtml();//null pointer error here
            }
        }

     /**
     * A BoardSquare is a square on the FiveInARow Board
     */
    public class BoardSquare {
        private Boolean avail; //is this square open to a piece
        private String color;//the color of the square when taken
        private int x, y; //the position of the square on the board

        /**
         * creates a basic boardSquare
         */
        public BoardSquare(int x, int y) {
            avail = true;
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            color = "red";//now added (thanks)
        }

        /**
         * returns the html form of this square
         */
        public String getHtml(){
            String html = "";

            html = "<div x='" + x + "' y='" + y + "' class='" + (avail ? "available" : color) + "'></div>";

            return html;
        }

        /**
         * if true, sets color to red
         * if false, sets color to green
         */
        public void takeSquare(Boolean red){
            if(red)
                color = "red";
            else 
                color = "green";
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does the VS debugger show? If attached to the process, it will break on the line causing the NRE and the values of the variables/expressions can be inspected. This will be your friend later, so get used to it now.

Comment: on boardHTML? if so set it to String.Empty before the loop. it doesn't like null +=.....

Answer (score 1):

Is the string field **Color** instantiated? doesn't seem like it.

There's your Null.

```
 html = "<div x='" + x + "' y='" + y + "' class='" + (avail ? "available" : color) + "'></div>";
```

The constructor should be like this:

```
public BoardSquare(int x, int y) {
            avail = true;
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            Color = "white";
        }
```

Comment: One line above `html` is set to an empty string.'

Comment: Ah, you meant `color`, I see.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  It still says my null is at boardHtml += board[i][k].getHtml();//null pointer error here

Comment: @user1416301: Then `boardHtml` is `null`

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an [array of arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx) (also known as jagged arrays), which I don't think is what you want.  You are probably looking for a [multidimensional](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) array:

```
BoardSquare[,] board = new BoardSquare[15,15];
```

Then when you assign to it:

```
board[i,k] = new BoardSquare(i, k);
boardHtml += board[i,k].getHtml();
```

Comment: Well that certainly worked.  thanks a bunch.  What is the difference anyway?  I tried to find out, but to no avail

Comment: I added a link to the MSDN description of jagged arrays.